# Me sale es siguente error: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'cv::imshow'

Tags: python, opencv

Ese es mi codigo:

```
# Contonrno de la Imagen
from cv2 import cv2

Foto = cv2.imread('contorno.jpg')
cv2.imshow('imagen', Foto)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Parece todo bien pero el ejecutarlo me sale el siguiente error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\eseba\Documents\Proyects\Python\Curso\Reconocimiento Facial\1-Contorno.py", line 5, in <module>
    cv2.imshow('imagen', Foto)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.1) C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-5rb_9df3\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:376: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'cv::imshow'
```

Ayuda por favor que ya no se que hacer :,c

Answer (score 1):

Posiblemente la ruta a la imagen este mal. Cuando abres una imagen mediante `imread` debes verificar que el objeto retornado no sea `None`, en caso de ser `None` significa que hubo un error durante la lectura de imagen.

```py
import cv2

PATH = '....jpg'
image = cv2.imread(PATH)

if image is None:
    print('Error durante la lectura de la imagen')
else:
    cv2.imshow('Imagen', image)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Deberás poner la ruta completa de donde este tu archivo y entre parenteís es en ms... Deberías poner 1000, para que sea 1 segundo.

```
from cv2 import cv2
Foto=cv2.imread('MonedasContorno\contorno.jpg')
cv2.imshow('imagen',Foto)
cv2.waitKey(1000)
```

Answer (score -1):

Poner la ruta completa en el `PATH` puede ser útil. Así te asegurarás de que no es incorrecta:

```
import cv2

PATH = 'reconocimiento_facial\monedasContorno\contorno.jpg'
image = cv2.imread(PATH)

if image is None:
    print('Error durante la lectura de la imagen')
else:
    cv2.imshow('Imagen', image)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Hay otra respuesta como la tuya, pero la otra explica las cosas. Eso la hace valiosa como respuesta.